# creating single view with elements created programmatically and loaded from nib

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I like using nib files to configure some subviews, but for other subviews i prefer to create them programmatically.  What is the preferred method to programmatically add elements into a view loaded from a nib or change element properties?  Right now I do it in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-(void)viewDidLoad` is the correct location for these customizations. And for removing any references to these customizations do so in `-(void)viewDidUnload`. Doing so in viewWillAppear may cause you to end up with multiple copies of you added elements since it is called each time the view is shown, especially in a `UINavigationController`.